# Read Current Data From Asp.Table

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

i have a table like this

```
<asp:Table ID="model" runat='server'>
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableHeaderCell class="col-xs-2">
        Name
        </asp:TableHeaderCell>
        <asp:TableHeaderCell class="col-xs-2">
        Barcode
        </asp:TableHeaderCell>
        <asp:TableHeaderCell class="col-xs-2">
        Row
        </asp:TableHeaderCell>
        <asp:TableHeaderCell class="col-xs-2">
        Pos
        </asp:TableHeaderCell>
        <asp:TableHeaderCell class="col-xs-2">

        </asp:TableHeaderCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

and a javascript Function to add row in the table from 4 label

```
function add() {
    var contentName = $('#name').val();
    var contentBarcode = $('#barcode').val();
    var contentRow = $('#row').val();
    var contentPos = $('#pos').val();
    if (contentName !== "" && contentBarcode !== "" && contentRow !== "" && contentPos !== "") {
        var table = document.getElementById("model");
        var row2 = table.insertRow();
        var name = row2.insertCell(0);
        var barcode = row2.insertCell(1);
        var row = row2.insertCell(2);
        var pos = row2.insertCell(3);
        var del = row2.insertCell(4);
        del.innerHTML = " <button onclick=\"$(this).closest('tr').remove();\">X</button>";
        name.innerHTML = contentName;
        barcode.innerHTML = contentBarcode;
        row.innerHTML = contentRow;
        pos.innerHTML = contentPos;
    }
}
```

when I finished populating the table I needed to read the content of the table  and put in a c# variable. I tried to use model.Rows but i get only the header.
Is it possible to take the content of the table?

Comment: its because you are adding the rows using javascript hence its not readable in the backend as its not saved in the viewstate I think

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, `copyTbl` is my table name as on my page I have multiple tables,  then i find each td in the row, and then use the orginal position to get the data.

I am going to assume that you know how to get the val(), innterHTML, etc... from there

```
var i = 0;
var arr = new Array();
var copyRows = $("#copyTbl tbody tr"); //Get ALL Rows 

$("#copyTbl tbody tr").each(function () {
var copyTd = $(copyRows[i]).find("td");
                var row = {

    BranchText: copyTd[0].innerText,// these get the html value of the table cells
    BranchTown: copyTd[1].innerText // these get the html value of the table cells

};

arr.push(row);

i++;

});
```

This then puts it all into an array, which is all of your table data that you can then pass to your ViewModel

Comment: i'm a beginner, how can i pass to ViewModel?

Comment: i'll revise the answer shortly

Comment: where is copyRows[i]?

Comment: I have edited that part of the question. I am doing it this way, because of various other things going on in my own script, however I think you can replace it with `$(this).find("td");`